# Why does the Relative Reference not work?

Tags: javascript, html

I used this line of code in my HTML file (in VSCode)

```
[<script type="module" src="./classDef.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="./scripts.js"></script>][1]
```

but faced this error massage in Chrome Console:

`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "classDef.js". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`

what is the problem or where I made a mistake? Thank you in advance

---

I tested and notice error is shown when I start to insert this code in js file:

```
import Book from '27classdef.js'

const iceAndFire = new Book(
    "a261",
    "Ice and Fire",
    "George R.R. Martin",
    "Fiction",
    352,
);

console.log(iceAndFire);
```

Comment: Is there a file named "classDef.js" in the same folder as this html? Remember that URLs are case sensitive.

Comment: Yes, they are in same folder.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the file name directly as:

```
[<script type="module" src="classDef.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="scripts.js"></script>][1]
```

Instead of src="**./classDef.js**" or src="**./scripts.js**"

Comment: I tested and notice error is shown when start to insert this code in js file:

import Book from '27classdef.js'

const iceAndFire = new Book(
    "a261",
    "Ice and Fire",
    "George R.R. Martin",
    "Fiction",
    352,
);

console.log(iceAndFire);

Comment: @kavehmoi so whats the question here?

Comment: I tested and notice error is shown when start to insert this code in js file:

import Book from '27classdef.js'

const iceAndFire = new Book(
    "a261",
    "Ice and Fire",
    "George R.R. Martin",
    "Fiction",
    352,
);

console.log(iceAndFire);

Comment: I am sorry @kavehmoi, I am not understanding your question

Comment: Thanks for your help, I found my mistake, a mistake in js script code causes the Error!